# How to find an object in array of objects by a deep path?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects which have a property `.names` which is another object.

I am using lodash...is there a helper method to get the user whose yahoo name is `foo` in the following example?

```
const users = [{
    names: {
        yahoo: 'foo',
        gmail: 'bar'
    }
}, {
    names: {
        yahoo: 'foo2',
        gmail: 'bar2'
    }   
}];
```

Comment: [__`Array#find`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should do this...

Comment: can you provide an example of `Array#find`?

Comment: Provided link has few examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**find**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#find) with a custom predicate:

```
var result = _.find(users, function(user) {
  return user.names.yahoo === 'foo';
});
```

```js
users = [{
  names: {
   yahoo: 'foo',
   gmail: 'bar'
  }
}, {
  names: {
   yahoo: 'foo2',
   gmail: 'bar2'
  }   
}];

var result = _.find(users, function(user) {
  return user.names.yahoo === 'foo';
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can also do it shorthand 
`_.find(users, { names: { yahoo: 'foo' } })`